# Second div does not show on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle

I have a problem, where I wish to toggle two divs (each in a column of their own), when a mouse covers over an element on page.

At this point only div (.text_2) reacts when .item-2 is hovered, but I also need text.2.2 to react, and appear (this div is placed in the next column).

I have tried a couple of different things in order to make this work. for example this

```
    $('.item-2').hover(function() {
        $('.text_2').toggleClass('hide_default');
    }, function(){
    $('.button-rounded').toggleClass('hide_default') {
        $('.text_2.2').toggleClass('hide_default');
    });
});
```

Here's my code so far

```js
$(".item-1").hover(function(){ 
    $('#text_1').toggleClass('hide_default');
 }, function(){
  $('#text_1').toggleClass('hide_default');
});


$(".item-2").hover(function(){ 
    $('.text_2').toggleClass('hide_default');
 }, function(){
  $('.text_2').toggleClass('hide_default');
});
```

```css
/* Body */

* {
  margin: auto;
  padding: o;
}

html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

/* Header */

#main{
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Contacts */

#contact{
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 25px;
font-size: 27px;
font-family: 'Times New Roman';
color: red;
}


#About{
margin: 50px; 
}


/* Slider */

.slider {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;

  background-color: white; color: #000;
  font-size: 27px;

  min-height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  clear: both;

  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;

  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 18px;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
}



/* New slider */

#container_1{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.hide_default {
  display: none;
}

#hide_default_2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sofia Bordoni</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="main">

          <div id="contact">
            <div class="item item-1">
                 Sofia Bordoni
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   sofiabordoni@gmail.com  
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   0045 &nbsp;9164&nbsp;6938
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   About
         </div>
          </div>
                

 
<div id="container_1">

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_2">

     <img class="Image" src="Images/SgDOoMc9ShRg0Zpr.png" width="200px">

   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_3">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Merry Christmas NC-kopi.gif" width="175px">
    
   </div>


   <div class="item" data-target="#text_4">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/poster_mockup_MD1-kopi 2.jpg" width="250px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_5">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/2Tecnica_MENU_bAGLIONI_DROGHERIA_CREATIVA-kopi 2.png" width="300px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_6">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Sofia_Bordoni_Portfolio_Tassinari_Vetta-7.png" width="350px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_7">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Snooze Bed Linen 200x2201.png" width="250px">
    
   </div>


   <div class="item" data-target="#text_8">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/plakat.png" width="250px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_9">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/mani-sito_2.png" width="250px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_10">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Sofia_Bordoni_Portfolio-3.png" width="250px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_11">

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Imprint Towel 70x1402-kopi.png" width="200px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_12" >

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-04-29 kl. 11.37.09 kopi.png" width="350px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_13" >

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Holiday_Greeting_Main_NY-kopi.jpg" width="175px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_14" >

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-04-15 kl. 14.49.35.png" width="350px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_15" >

    <img class="Image" src="Images/Betafactory.gif" width="450px">
    
   </div>

   <div class="item" data-target="#text_16" >

    <img class="Image" src="Images/330393_Normann_Copenhagen_Christmas_Candle_2018_Black_01.png" width="150px">
    
   </div>
 
 </div>
</div>

<div class="slider" style="max-height: 100vh max-height:70px;">


 <div class="nav-item column column-1">

   <p class="hide_default" id="text_1" style="color: #3333ff">
               
    I love the memory of my childhood, that was full of colors, paper, pencils, and handcraft works. Developing an obsession towards various creative fields. Photography, developing analog photos. Architecture, seeing buildings as shapes, volumes and material combinations. Typography, as well as observing letters as shapes with an entrenched character. Upon realizing that graphic design is the field that was capable to bring together all of these passions I followed them with enthusiasm.
     </p>


       <p class="hide_default" id="text_2" style="color: blue">      
     Category: Objects
    </p>




 </div>

   <div class="nav-item column column-2">

     <p  class="hide_default" id="text_2.2" style="color: blue">
     Project: Normann Copenhagen Christmas Collection 
     <br>
     Candle
   </p>


 </div>

 <div class="nav-item column column-3">


 </div>

 <div class="nav-item column column-3">


 </div>



   </div>

    <script src="Onhover.js"></script>
    <script src="HoverColor.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: You'll want to reference the ID of text_2.2, but it looks as though you're trying to reference it's ID as a class. That is, try swapping the . for a #.
$('.text_2').toggleClass('hide_default'); should be 
$('#text_2').toggleClass('hide_default');

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the structure in the HTML from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61480864/519413) I provided to use the `data-target` to genericise the logic and keep it DRY.

As such you just need to amend the selector in the `data-target` to match both the `#text_2` and `#text_2.2` element. Note that the `.` in the latter selector will need to be escaped so that it's not interpreted as a class selector.

```js
$(".item").hover(function() {
  $(this.dataset.target.replace('.', '\\.')).toggleClass('hide_default');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: auto;
  padding: o;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#contact {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: red;
}

#About {
  margin: 50px;
}

.slider {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 27px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  clear: both;
  transition: all 1s;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 18px;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
}

#container_1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.hide_default {
  display: none;
}

#hide_default_2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="contact">
    <div class="item item-1" data-target="#text_1">
      Sofia Bordoni &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; sofiabordoni@gmail.com &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0045 &nbsp;9164&nbsp;6938 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; About
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container_1">
    <!-- note additional id selector in data-target here -->
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_2, #text_2.2"><img class="Image" src="Images/SgDOoMc9ShRg0Zpr.png" width="200px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_3"><img class="Image" src="Images/Merry Christmas NC-kopi.gif" width="175px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_4"><img class="Image" src="Images/poster_mockup_MD1-kopi 2.jpg" width="250px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_5"><img class="Image" src="Images/2Tecnica_MENU_bAGLIONI_DROGHERIA_CREATIVA-kopi 2.png" width="300px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_6"><img class="Image" src="Images/Sofia_Bordoni_Portfolio_Tassinari_Vetta-7.png" width="350px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_7"><img class="Image" src="Images/Snooze Bed Linen 200x2201.png" width="250px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_8"><img class="Image" src="Images/plakat.png" width="250px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_9"><img class="Image" src="Images/mani-sito_2.png" width="250px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_10"><img class="Image" src="Images/Sofia_Bordoni_Portfolio-3.png" width="250px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_11"><img class="Image" src="Images/Imprint Towel 70x1402-kopi.png" width="200px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_12"><img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-04-29 kl. 11.37.09 kopi.png" width="350px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_13"><img class="Image" src="Images/Holiday_Greeting_Main_NY-kopi.jpg" width="175px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_14"><img class="Image" src="Images/Skærmbillede 2020-04-15 kl. 14.49.35.png" width="350px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_15"><img class="Image" src="Images/Betafactory.gif" width="450px"></div>
    <div class="item" data-target="#text_16"><img class="Image" src="Images/330393_Normann_Copenhagen_Christmas_Candle_2018_Black_01.png" width="150px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider" style="max-height: 100vh max-height:70px;">
  <div class="nav-item column column-1">
    <p class="hide_default" id="text_1" style="color: #3333ff">
      I love the memory of my childhood, that was full of colors, paper, pencils, and handcraft works. Developing an obsession towards various creative fields. Photography, developing analog photos. Architecture, seeing buildings as shapes, volumes and material
      combinations. Typography, as well as observing letters as shapes with an entrenched character. Upon realizing that graphic design is the field that was capable to bring together all of these passions I followed them with enthusiasm.
    </p>
    <p class="hide_default" id="text_2" style="color: blue">
      Category: Objects
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item column column-2">
    <p class="hide_default" id="text_2.2" style="color: blue">
      Project: Normann Copenhagen Christmas Collection
      <br> Candle
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item column column-3"></div>
  <div class="nav-item column column-3"></div>
</div>
```

A better approach would be to remove the `.` in the `id` attribute completely, as it avoids confusion with class selectors. Then the JS can be made even more simple:

```html
<div class="nav-item column column-2">
  <p class="hide_default" id="text_2_2" style="color: blue">
    Project: Normann Copenhagen Christmas Collection
    <br> Candle
  </p>
</div>
```

```js
$(".item").hover(function() {
  $(this.dataset.target).toggleClass('hide_default');
});
```

Comment: Hey Rory

Thank you so much for your elaborate reply and patience. Right now I feel a bit stupid, because I still haven’t managed to make it work.

I have taken the forst code you, posted here and tried with both  with


$(".item").hover(function() {
  $(this.dataset.target.replace(‘.text_2’, ‘.text_2.2’)).toggleClass('hide_default');
});

$(".item").hover(function() {
  $(this.dataset.target.replace(‘#text_2’, ‘#text_2.2’)).toggleClass('hide_default');
});


I am not sure about the use of the \\, but I have tried with them as well. I have tried a lot of other stuff, but nothin